# How do I space out TR in table?

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to space out the TR? So there is a gap between "@" and "m" so displays like this:

```
@@@@     mmmmm
```

HTML:

```
<div id="aero">
<table id="dedicatedserverstable" style='border: 1'>
<tbody>
<tr>@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</tr>
<tr>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#aero {
width: 800px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background:#F2F7FA;
padding: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
min-height: 120px;
font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #868686;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #868686;
color: #666;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Here is code:

http://jsfiddle.net/TGKa7/2/

Comment: First, you need `<td>` elements inside of your `<tr>` elements. Second, you can use CSS to apply padding or a margin to said `<td>` elements.

Comment: updated fiddle with the right markup: http://jsfiddle.net/TGKa7/1/

Answer (score 1):

To start with, your HTML markup is incorrect. The only acceptable child of a `<tr>` element is a `<td>`. This means you cannot have text directly inside of a `<tr>`. You will need to change your markup to something like this:

```
<table id="dedicatedserverstable" style='border: 1'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</td>
      <td>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then, you can use CSS to apply padding in between the two table cells like so:

```
#dedicatedserverstable td {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e6DFT/

Comment: thanks for reply I think this will do exactly what I need it to do. I will test it live and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `td`'s inside your table rows, also you have one too many closing `tr` tags

```
  <tr><td>@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</td></tr>
  <tr><td>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</td></tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5fpVL/

Comment: thanks for reply I have fixed the extra tr typo. But this still doesn't create a gap between the @ and m. I want display like (above just added)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the result on the same line you should really create table divisions (), that way the "@@@" will be separated from the "mmm". Something like this:

```
<div id="aero">
<table id="dedicatedserverstable" style='border: 1'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</td>
            <td>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

On the other hand if you want it to be on two separate lines it should go like this:

```
<div id="aero">
<table id="dedicatedserverstable" style='border: 1'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between your two snippets of code.

Answer (score 0):

Dont really know what you mean by spacing out, but maybe this helps:

MARKUP:

```
<div id="aero">
    <table id="dedicatedserverstable" style='border: 1'>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td class = "first">@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</td></tr>
            <tr><td>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#aero {
    width: 800px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background:#F2F7FA;
    padding: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
    min-height: 120px;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #868686;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #868686;
    color: #666;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#aero td.first {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TGKa7/13/

And if you need the gap in the same line, use this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TGKa7/18/

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to target the first table row and align content to the top in it:

```
<style>
tr:nth-child(1) {height: 50px; vertical-align: top}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
<td>@@@@@</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>mmmmmm</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

[image]